# Cannot read configuration defined in config.xml file inside frontend area

Tags: magento2.4

I'm pretty new to Magento 2, so most probably I'm missing something simple here.

I've purchased a certification prep course. One of the first examples was about config merging and overriding. There were two modules: one with a config.xml file in its `/etc` folder (let's call it module *A*), containing this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <example>
            <values>
                <shipping_method>fedex</shipping_method>
                <payment_method>paypal</payment_method>
            </values>
        </example>
    </default>
</config>
```

And then another one, module *B*, with another config.xml file placed in `etc/frontend` with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <example>
            <values>
                <shipping_method>ups</shipping_method>
            </values>
        </example>
    </default>
</config>
```

Due to the sequence defined in module.xml, module *A* loads after module *B*. When I inspected the values for those configuration nodes, everything seemed to work fine.

But then I tried to invert the order, I realized Magento wasn't loading the config.xml file in module *B*, so overriding wasn't actually happening.

To double-check that, I defined a new module, and inside its `etc/frontend` folder I created a config.xml file with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <example>
            <values>
                <shipping_method>fedex</shipping_method>
                <payment_method>paypal</payment_method>
            </values>
        </example>
    </default>
</config>
```

I've also created an Action class with this content:

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /** @var RawFactory */
    private $rawFactory;

    /** @var ScopeConfigInterface */
    private $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        RawFactory $rawFactory,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->rawFactory = $rawFactory;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $shippingMethod = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('example/values/shipping_method');
        $paymentMethod = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('example/values/payment_method');

        $output = $this->rawFactory->create();
        $output->setContents(implode("<br/>", [
            'Shipping method: ' . $shippingMethod,
            'Payment method: ' . $paymentMethod
        ]));

        return $output;
    }
}
```

The issue is `$shippingMethod` and `$paymentMethod` are both null, unless I move the config.xml file to `etc` root folder. I've run this on that controller method:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State')->getAreaCode();
```

And the result is *frontend*.

What am I missing? I should be able to get the values from config.xml when it's located in the frontend area, should I? I've disabled the cache, cleared opcache anytime I made a change, run `magento setup:di:compile`, and it always returns null for the configuration values when config.xml is inside `etc/frontend`.

In short, why Magento is not able to load config.xml from `etc/frontend`?

Comment: What is your exact requirement? What you want to do?

Comment: Right now I'm just learning. I found an example of a module overriding the config.xml values from another one, and while tweaking things I came up with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Magento doesn't load config.xml from specific area folders: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/config/config-files.html

So not loading etc/frontend/config.xml is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> **config.xml** is located in etc folder.

**So simply move this file**

From :-

```
etc/frontend
```

To :-

```
etc/
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the **config.xml** file is created in app/etc. In your case, it is located in etc/frontend so Magento will not be able to read your config file.